# In Perl - How to normalize Path for windows

Tags: regex, perl

I am new in Perl, but i need to know how to get variable contain specific path normalized for windows.

Thanks,
MaMd0u7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html

```
use File::Spec::Win32
my $dir = File::Spec::Win32->catfile('directory','tree','file.html');
print $dir;

output: directory\tree\file.html
```

any use?

Comment: Or maybe he wants `canonpath` from that same module